# Loading Issues with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Loading gifs into my `UITableViewCell` using `SDWebImage`. It's actually really fast, but the `tableview` doesn't seem to load up until the user actually scrolls the `tableview`.

Any suggestions for how to fix this issue?

This is my `UITableView`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.gifArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

RDGifGridTableViewCell *cell = (RDGifGridTableViewCell *)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RDGifGridTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.urlLabel.text = [self.gifArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.urlLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.urlLabel.text] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];

return cell;
}
```

This is how I add content to the array which occurs in viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSArray *idArray = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
                for (NSDictionary *ids in idArray) {

                    NSDictionary *images = ids[@"images"];
                    NSDictionary *fixedHeightImage = images[@"fixed_width"];
                    self.gifURL = fixedHeightImage[@"url"];
                    [self.gifArray addObject:self.gifURL];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
```

Comment: Could you post the code of "sd_setImageWithURL:" method. I think it has the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The following line might be the problem

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

When your cells are being reused you are using a different cellIdentfier `RDGifGridTableViewCell`.

It should be the same cell being reused.

So just fix this line and use that variable again when it's nil to avoid such mistake, oh and while you're at it, consider renaming your variable to first letter lowercase `myIdentifier` as Objective C naming convention suggests.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"RDGifGridTableViewCell";

RDGifGridTableViewCell *cell = (RDGifGridTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RDGifGridTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.urlLabel.text = [self.gifArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.urlLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.urlLabel.text] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it, meda.

Comment: Try it with `Cell` as the identifier, it could only be one or the other

Comment: I have always been using the same identifier. I have it named in storyboards.

Comment: @user3765569 I dont think you are seeing what Im trying to point out, take a look at my last edit

Comment: Yeah that didn't fix my load issues or anything.

Comment: you mentionned that it only works when you scroll, try this http://pastie.org/9315276

Comment: If you want to load all images at once, then don't use reuseIdentifier, because reuseIdentifier tell cells to reuse, so as and when cells are scroll new data which needs to be visible will be loaded and if you don't use it all the data load at once(however it is not a good practice) But depends on your requirement and data size.